# Textfield cannot type in or not showing key in number

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I have a text field named "Security Code" which using number keyboard. But when I type in, nothing showing. (The other text fields all working well)

[image: Cannot Type in "Security Code" Textfield]

Error Message:

```
Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 20615_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

I searched this error message and got the answer that using `hardware->keybard->connect hardware keyboard` to solve. But I think it is another issue and do not solve my problem. For both real device and simulator this problem both exist. By the way, the number keyboard will pop up normally, but when I tap on the keyboard, nothing show in the textfield.

I tried to change the keyboard type from number pad to default or other keyboard but also not working.

I think it might because the text field is not getting what I type in correctly.

Here are some of my code: (AddCreditCardVC.swift)

```
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSecurityCode: SkyFloatingLabelTextField! {
        didSet{
            txtSecurityCode.isMandatory = true
        }
    }

    @objc func commonInit() {   
        txtSecurityCode.text = "abc"
        txtSecurityCode.isEnabled = false      
    }

    @objc func addCreditCard() {
        viewModel.securityCode = txtSecurityCode.text

        viewModel.addCreditCard(success: {
            // post noti
            self.postCreditCardUpdatedNoti()
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }) {
            self.showAlert($0)
        }
    }

    @objc func initTextFields() {
        creditCardMaskDelegate.listener = self
        txtSecurityCode.delegate = self
        setupSkyTextFields(textField: txtSecurityCode, placholder: "Security Code *", title: "SECURITY CODE *", text: "", isMandatory: true)
        [txtCreditCardNo,txtExpiryYear,txtExpiryMonth,txtSecurityCode].forEach {
            $0?.errorTextColor = .black 
        }
    }

extension AddCreditCardVC: MaskedTextFieldDelegateListener {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, didFillMandatoryCharacters complete: Bool, didExtractValue value: String) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

extension AddCreditCardVC: UITextFieldDelegate {


    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


        if textField == txtCreditCardNo {
            let card = STPCardValidator.brand(forNumber: textField.text ?? "")
            imgCardType.image = CardType(rawValue: card.rawValue)?.getCardLogo()
            cvcCount = CardType(rawValue: card.rawValue)?.getCvcCount() ?? 0
        }

        print("textField-->", txtSecurityCode)

        if textField  == txtSecurityCode {
            guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
            let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length
            return newLength <= cvcCount



        }
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == txtExpiryMonth {
            isExpireMonth = true
            expirePicker.isMonth = true
            expirePicker.setExpireMonth()
        }else if textField == txtExpiryYear {
            isExpireMonth = false
            expirePicker.setExpireYear()
        }
    }
}
```

For the `print("textField-->", txtSecurityCode)`, when I tap the keyboard in "security Code" textfield, it returns:

```
Optional(<SkyFloatingLabelTextField.SkyFloatingLabelTextField: 0x7fd3a4173800; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (24 3; 148 41); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003bfbed0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003463bc0>>)
```

Update:
From @matt's suggestion, added: return true in the first line of

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

and can type inside the textfield now. So the issue is that this function is not correct.

Comment: What happens if you just insert `return true` as the first line in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`? Does typing work then? If so, the problem is in your implementation of that method.

Comment: Hi @matt, thank you for the suggestion, I tried to add "return true", and it works. But I'm not sure what's wrong with the "if" condition in side this function.  It seems the txtSecurityCode I'm getting is wrong.

Comment: Ok but that’s very good work. Now we just need to fix that method. It’s night here but put that info into your question, I’m sure someone will help.

Comment: @matt, sure, thank you very much for your help!!! It's noon here. Good night.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Modified Code:

```
if textField  == txtSecurityCode {
            guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
            let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length

            let card = STPCardValidator.brand(forNumber: txtCreditCardNo.text ?? "")
            imgCardType.image = CardType(rawValue: card.rawValue)?.getCardLogo()
            cvcCount = CardType(rawValue: card.rawValue)?.getCvcCount() ?? 0

            return newLength <= cvcCount    
        }
```

This function is used to limit the textfield "Security Code" length according to the card type. But previously the code is always getting "cvcCount" value as "0", and the function will always return "false". That's why it cannot input anything. After modified, the "cvcCount" will return value according to card type, and the whole function will keep returning "true" when the input number length is less or equal to "cvcCount"